# Stripe: Expire/Cancel subscription after n payments

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

In our app, we create subscriptions for users which is working good, subscription can vary on type of plan. But I am not able to figure out how to cancel subscription after user has fully paid.

Is there any parameter we can tell stripe at the time of creation of subscription that tells it when subscription should cancel OR tell it to cancel it after `n` number of payments?

So essentially if customer bought a product which costs 1000, we would charge him 100 a month but then automatically cancel subscription once he has fully paid.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a subscription in Stripe, there is no way to tell Stripe to stop the subscription after N months or when a given amount in reached.

From the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/canceling-pausing):

> By default, a subscription continues, and the customer continues to be
>   billed, until it’s canceled

So what you could do is to cancel the subscription once a given condition is met.

You could use **webhooks** to get notified every time the customer is billed, at the end of every billing cycle, using the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event (documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded)).

Somehow you could keep track of the total amount paid by the customer in your database and the amount that is left before the item you sell is "fully paid".

Everytime you get the webhook, you increment the total and, if the required amount in reached, you cancel the subscription so that the customer will not be billed the next month.

Comment: Thanks yet because there is no way built-in way in stripe, that is the route iam going with for now. Only caveat with this is that what happens if customer is billed and their webhook service is down... hope they will provide this facility in future to tell when to cancel at the time of creation of subscription. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I answered this here: [Stripe cancel subscription at specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431030/stripe-cancel-subscription-at-specific-date)

> Stripe just added this to their API and I happened to stumble upon it. They have a field called "cancel_at" that can be set to a date in the future. They don't have this attribute listed in their documentation since it is so new. You can see the value in the response object here:
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=php
>
> I've tested this using .NET and can confirm it sets the subscription to expire at value you provide.

Comment: it's invalid request for canceling subscription. `'Received unknown parameter: cancel_at'`. It allows for update, waiting for a result if subscription will be canceled in the future

Comment: @Adam, this isn't for cancelling.  There is a specific call for that, this is to set the date the subscription should end.