# Stripe cancel subscription at specific date

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using [StripeAPI](https://stripe.com/docs/api) in PHP and I don't know how can I stop a customer subscription at a specific date.

I know there is an option for cancel subscription immediatly :

```
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve('sub_49ty4767H20z6a');
$subscription->cancel();
```

Or for cancel subscription  at the end of the current billing period (for the duration of time the customer has already paid for) with :

```
$subscription->cancel(['at_period_end' => true]);
```

With this option, the cancellation is scheduled.

But how can I cancel a subscription at a specific date? In my system, a user can ask for a cancellation but he has to wait for a specific date (something like at least stay X months as a subscriber)

Do you know how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to program out that logic on your own side.  Stripe doesn't have a built-in construct for that.

Answer (score 4):

Stripe just added this to their API and I happened to stumble upon it.  They have a field called "cancel_at" that can be set to a date in the future.  They don't have this attribute listed in their documentation since it is so new.  You can see the value in the response object here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=php

I've tested this using .NET and can confirm it sets the subscription to expire at value you provide.

Comment: `They have a field called "cancel_at" ` . It appears they do not.

Comment: @SephReed, just verified via the link that the field is still there in the response as noted.  We are still using the field in production as a request without issue.

Comment: I found it.  It is not searchable at all (through google or their api).  Also, they overload typical search so you double can't search it.  There is no documentation for it.  But, it can be seen in one of the examples.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, yes. Good question. Here's a check/execute example:

```
$today = time();
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve('Their Customer ID');
$signUpDate = $customer->subscriptions->data[0]->created;

// This will define the date where you wish to cancel them on.
// The example here is 30 days from which they initially subscribed.
$cancelOnDate = strtotime('+30 day', $signUpDate);

// If today is passed or equal to the date you defined above, cancel them.
if ($today >= $cancelOnDate) {
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve('sub_49ty4767H20z6a');
    $subscription->cancel();
}
```

Here's an example of setting cancellation upon them subscribing:

```
$today = time();

// Cancel them 30 days from today
$cancelAt = strtotime('+30 day', $today);

$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    "customer" => 'Their Customer ID',
    "plan" => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    "cancel_at" => $cancelAt
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late, but I had the same problem and checked your post for help. We want to offer a season pass for the users, so if they cancel the subscription the payment will end at the end of the season, for example every year in June.

After a lot of research I have found a solution in the laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#cancelling-subscriptions), that might help. For my solution it was not `cancel_at` but `cancelAt`. Not much difference, but helped me a lot :)

```
$subscription = $user->subscription('default')->cancelAt(
        Carbon::create(2021,6,30)
    );
```

Best,
Timo